# Orthogonal projection on vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

$w = \begin{bmatrix}
3\\ 
4\\
-3\\
\end{bmatrix}$

$s = \begin{bmatrix}
1/\sqrt{12}\\
1/\sqrt{12}\\
1/\sqrt{12}\\
\end{bmatrix}$

I am trying to compute the orthogonal projection of w onto s. I know how to compute a projection with two components, but not three and orthogonal. Not really sure where to start so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The projection is $P={{W\cdot S} \over {S \cdot S} }S$.

For two vectors $A=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $B=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ the dot product is $A\cdot B= a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3$.

So here $W\cdot S= 3 *1/\sqrt{12}+4*1/\sqrt{12}+(-3)*1/\sqrt{12}=4/\sqrt{12}$.

And $S\cdot S=1/\sqrt{12}*1/\sqrt{12}+1/\sqrt{12}*1/\sqrt{12}+1/\sqrt{12}*1/\sqrt{12}=3/12=1/4 $

Finally ${{{W\cdot S} \over {S \cdot S} }S}={(4/\sqrt{12})\over(1/4)}(1/\sqrt{12}, 1/\sqrt{12},1/\sqrt{12})={4\over3}(1,1,1)$

To read about it [go to here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).

Note that the normal component of $W$ on $S$,(in the above article referred to as "rejection") is $W-P$.